# How do I set ISO country codes (e.g. en-US) in Content-Language on a Google Cloud Storage object?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

We're using Google Storage Transfer Service to migrate S3 buckets to Google Cloud Storage, but we're getting a lot of INVALID_ARGUMENT errors. On further investigation, we narrowed it down to the files that have a Content-Language metadata set of `en-US`. I'm able to reproduce the same error using `gsutil setmeta -h "Content-Language:en-US" "gs://<bucket>/*.html"` which gives me `BadRequestException: 400 Invalid argument.`

The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata#content-language) say "Refer to ISO 639-1 language codes for the supported values of this metadata," and sure enough just setting `en` works, but through the Google Cloud Console I'm able to set a value of `en_US` by setting the language to `English (United States)`. I can see that it's calling some Google RPC endpoint with  `"request":{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.internal.cloud.console.clientapi.storage.UpdateObjectRequest","object":{"resourceName":"projects/_/buckets/<bucket>/objects/<object>","objectMetadata":{"contentLanguage":"en_US"}},"fieldMask":"object_metadata.content_language"}`

But when I try to set `en_US` through gsutil or set it in S3 and run Storage Transfer Service I get the same invalid argument error. How do I add a country code to my content language in Google Cloud Storage?

Comment: Are you saying that Google Storage Transfer Service is failing based on the value of the metadata **Content-Language** OR that Cloud Storage does not support **en-US**? In yes to either, I think you have identified a bug. Since the Console GUI can set the value, try using the SDK to do the same. Link to examples: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/samples/storage-set-metadata#storage_set_metadata-python Link to report bugs: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Comment: I'm saying Storage Transfer Service and gsutil error when I try to set it. I'm able to get close with the UI. When I try to use the SDK snippet you linked it shows up as a custom metadata field named the same as the metadata field I would expect it to change in the UI, which is at least not an error.

Comment: Did find [this stale feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/175105904) for Storage Transfer Service and added [my own](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/234852531) for gsutil.

Comment: I have upvoted each issue. I am very curious why this problem exists. Cloud Storage was one of the first public services and is used by millions. I guess that few set those headers. Post an answer with your bug tracker links as that is the answer as of today.